# Round all calculations to the nearest number

Tags: php, money-php

I am dealing with money and would love to round the numbers to the lowest payable amount on market. Let say I have a calculation resulting in:

- 25,467.56
- 5333.65
- 532
- 60
- 54

In the market the lowest amount payable is 50, so somehow these numbers have to be rounded to the nearest 50 and the result displayed should be:

- 25,450
- 5300
- 500
- 50
- 50

How do accurately and reliably do that? Does PHP offer a built in function to handle that? I tried to Google and get something to read but I got wrong answers so I must be using wrong keyword. Any pointer to the right direction is appreciated!

Note: I use [moneyphp](https://www.moneyphp.org/en/stable/) for financial calculation and this is a user feature so it is okay to loose that precision.

Comment: divide by 50, round down, multiply by 50.

Comment: can't believe it is that easy! Thank you.

Comment: The desired results 5300 and 500 shown for inputs of 5333.65 and 532 do not match the heading, nor do they match the accepted solution.
Please correct your examples.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title to match the whole body. Am not good at that and that help is appreciated. The body reflects what I want.

I have put a comment that accepted answer does not indeed answer exactly what I wanted but points me to the right direction. If you can put a better answer, I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has an built in round function. Using this and some calculations to round to 50 instead of 1 you get the code:

```
echo(round(x/50)*50);
```

Here x is the number it rounds.
This works by first getting how many multiples of 50 x is, rounding that and then multiplying it by 50 again to get the result.

Comment: I appreciate that. It does not do 100% but my main obstacle is definitely gone.
Again, thank you!